# Which orthonormal matrix of size $N \times N$ has the maximum sum of elements?

Tags: linear-algebra

In other words, I want to find
$$\max_\mathbf{U} \bf\underline{1}^TU\underline{1}$$
where $\mathbf{U}$ is an $N \times N$ real orthonormal matrix.

Since problems like this often have trivial solutions, I would guess the answer would be: any permutation matrix, whose elements sum to $N$. How do I prove this? I can prove it for $N=2$ matrix, but how do I prove this for an arbitrary $N$?

Comment: $U$ maximizes $\mathbf{1}^{\mathsf{T}}U\mathbf{1}$ if and only if the restriction of $U$ onto the orthogonal complement $W=\langle\mathbf{1}\rangle^{\perp}$ is again an orthogonal transformation from $W$ to $W$ itself. In other words, if $\mathfrak{B}=\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\mathbf{1}, \mathbf{u}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{u}_N \}$ is an orthonormal basis, then $U$ is a maximizer if and only if $$[U]_{\mathfrak{B}}^{\mathfrak{B}}=\left(\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}1& 0 \\ \hline 0 & \tilde{U} \end{array}\right)$$ for some $(N-1)\times(N-1)$ orthogonal matrix $\tilde{U}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the fact that $U$ is orthonormal, we have $$\vec{1}^TU\vec{1} = \left\langle\vec{1}, U\vec{1}\right\rangle \le \|\vec{1}\| \cdot \|U\vec{1}\| = \|\vec{1}\| \cdot \|\vec{1}\| = \|\vec{1}\|^2 = N.$$ As you noted, equality holds when $U$ is a permutation matrix, so $\displaystyle\max_U \vec{1}^TU\vec{1} = N$.